# Check if property exist before multiplying it to another property inside an object?

Tags: powershell

I have an object and iterating over it and multiplying A, B, C together. B is a list and I'm using the count of elements inside of it. Sometimes, B does not exist.

```
$sum = ( $arrOfObjects | forEach-Object {$_.A * $_.B.Count * $_.C.Count } | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

This works as long as A, B, C exist. Now, how do I create a check to make sure B exists before using its count.

If B doesn't exist, I'd like to use 1 as the number.

Comment: What's wrong with an `if` statement?

Comment: `@( $_.B ).Count` should be it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon and if that's 0 (zero)?

Comment: @Olaf that means trouble :) but OP specifically stated "if B doesn't exist" and we don't know what type of values `B` is holding

Comment: :-D ... hmmm ... @jsnoobie ... can u share some more infos?

Comment: @Olaf actually `@( 0 ).Count` is `1`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I don't know if that's possible in this case but I meant when `$_.B` is an empty array. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use a [ternary conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) for a concise solution:

```
$_.A * ($null -eq $_.B ? 1 : $_.B.Count) * $_.C.Count
```

In *Windows PowerShell*, use an `if` statement enclosed in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

```
$_.A * $(if ($null -eq $_.B) { 1 } else { $_.B.Count }) * $_.C.Count
```

Note:

- The solutions above do not distinguish between `$_` not having a `B` property and having such a property but *with a value of `$null`*
- If you need to distinguish these cases, replace `$null -eq $_.B` with 
  `$null -eq $_.psobject.Properties['B']`, which uses the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) for reflection in order to test the presence of a property with the given name.

  - This has the added advantage of not retrieving the *value* of the property during the test, which - situationally, though not typically - can be more costly than the reflection being performed.